Supabase RLS - violates row-level security if set to 'authenticated' users despite authenticated (via OAuth google)?
Not sure why I'm unable to set my RLS to be ALL (select/update/delete/insert) for only authenticated users.
If I have my RLS set to public, I'm able to view/insert to the products table. This is the example for the read access
create policy "PublicAccessToALL" 
on "public"."products" 
as permissive 
for ALL 
to public 
using (true);

Supabase Anon Access to All
Access to all works (the last item is the item inserted with the supabase RLS set as above)
However if I have it set as enabled for authenticated users only, it doesn't work. This is the example for the insert:
alter policy "Enable insert for authenticated users only"
on "public"."products"
to authenticated
with check (true);

I've also tried to do ALL access for authenticated users using
(auth.role() = 'authenticated') and it didn't work
Supabase RLS with auth.role() = authenticated
The users have to sign in via Google OAuth before they can access this page, so they should be authenticated. I assume the authentication also worked since it shows in the console
User is authenticated
